# Angular-Gantt is not responding when changing timezone to different timezone other than Default UTC (Etc/UTC)

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate, angular-gantt

I am using Angularjs v1.7.5 and [Angular-Gantt v2.0.0](https://www.angular-gantt.com/)

In addition, I am using ASP.Net Boilerplate v3.2.4 as a backend. multiple tenancy is disabled.

When setting timezone in Setting as (e.g: UTC+02:00 Damascus) or any other timezone other than Default UTC (Etc/UTC) the page is not responding and browser is freezing.

I've already tries using MomentJs instead of default javascript date and it's not working.

so my question here is whether anyone has experienced this problem and what is the solution for it.

**Workaround:**

Disabling multiple timezone support in Asp.Net Boilterplate by setting local timezone
in Global.asax as next :

```
Clock.Provider = ClockProviders.Local;
```

has solved the problem.

But I'm looking for a better way to solve the problem while keeping multiple timezone support.

Thank you guys in advanced.

Comment: What's the error in Logs.txt and browser console?

Comment: There are no errors in logs or console.. and all dates that I've entered are correct

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.